# RegEx to match M/YYYY, MM/YYYY , M/YY or MM/YY format

Tags: c#, regex

Need help finding or having a RegEx match a MM/YY or MM/YYYY format.  My RegExFu is weak and I'm not even sure where to begin writing this.

Months should be 1-12, years, well anything beyond 2009 should be valid.  Sorry for not mentioning more details before.  This is used as an expiration date.

I'll add a bounty for whomever goes above and beyond and validates MM/YY or MM/YYYY format that is >= today's date.  No sense letting expired stuff past the first validation layer.

---

I feel bad since I changed my requirements and had to be more specific in what I needed mid-question so I'll award bounties to all those who answered once the no-bounty window expires.

Comment: You will like http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for a tutorial and http://weitz.de/regex-coach/ for trying them out. (\d\d)/(\d\d) is a start for mm/yy.  Sry, I'm currently too lazy for the rest.

Comment: If you are planning to allow users to input `2 digit years`, I don't recommend that. Prefer `4 digits` (full digits) always.

Comment: @BrunoLM, well the API I'm working with accepts MM/YY format so any little perk I can give to my users I'll take.

Comment: So you want `year >= 2010` valid?

Comment: How will you use it? Where will you validate? Have you considered a calendar control, with minimal date?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$
```

Matches months

```
// 10 to 12 | 01 to 09 | 1 to 9
(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)
```

And years

```
// 2000 to 2099 | 1900 to 1999
// 01 to 09 | 10 to 99
(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)
```

---

To match anything `>= 2010`

```
/^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/([2-9]\d[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d)$/;
```

Result:

```
12/2009 : false
1/2010  : true
12/2011 : true
12/9011 : true
12/07   : false
12/17   : true
```

Comment: @Bruno, that's basically my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're excluding the year `00`? It's probably not good practice to use since it's kind of confusing, but it seems like it's still perfectly valid. Or does C# not allow that for date formats?

Comment: @eldarerathis: The OP didn't say what ranges he is expecting. I decided to exclude `00` because it seems ambiguous to me. `00` is `1900` or `2000`? Anyway, this is just one example. What I recommend is to use `4 digits` always.

Comment: @jfar: 1/81 is not of the format MM/YYYY or MM/YY. `01/81` would be, but you should edit into your question if you also want M/YYYY and M/YY.

Comment: @jfar: Thanks :). I've updated with `anything beyond 2009`. I'm assuming `x >= 2010` is valid. And assuming 2 digits are `20xx`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(19|2[0-1])?\d{2}$
```

Constrains to one and two-digit months (01-12, 1-12) and two and four years (00-99, 1900-2199).

Comment: this matches "MM/YYY" aswell.

Comment: @Brad, this isn't matching 11/81

Comment: The first half won't accept a valid, two-digit month. It's expecting 4 digits: http://rubular.com/r/5yiqpDFKyy

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?<month>\d{2})/(?<year>\d{2}|\d{4})");
var month = re.Match(yourString).Groups["month"];
...
```

An alternative is:

```
if(dateStr.Length == 5)
    myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("MM/YY", dateStr);
else
    myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("MM/YYYY", dateStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ParseExact.  That makes my validation even better.

Comment: [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) can take an array of formats, which is defiantly better than a regex.

Answer (score 0):

[@BrunoLM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3944488/5292302),

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$
```

matches "0/2009". May I suggest a minor improvement:

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|[1-9])\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$
```