# Jquery Function for validation

Tags: jquery

I would like to validate my textbox which accepts Academic Year as input in the format 
**YYYY-YY**. How do I write a regular expression validation/ jquery client validation function for this?

```
function parseDate() {
    alert("yeah");
    var sAcadYearName = document
            .getElementById('<%= txtAcademicYearName.ClientID%>');
    var m = sAcadYearName.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1]) : null;
}
```

Comment: are you using any validation plugin?

Comment: In that case you need to go for an regex based validation

Comment: Yeah I did that, but the expression /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/ doesn't work ...

Comment: can you share the code what you have done

Comment: function parseDate() {
    alert("yeah");
    var sAcadYearName = document.getElementById('<%=     txtAcademicYearName.ClientID%>');
    var m = sAcadYearName.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1]) : null;
    }

Comment: `var sAcadYearName = document.getElementById('<%= txtAcademicYearName.ClientID%>'); should be `var sAcadYearName = document.getElementById('<%= txtAcademicYearName.ClientID%>').value;

Comment: I can't find any relation between the question and the code

Comment: other than that the code seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dnR8Q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 <input id="txtdob" type="text"/>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
                        ControlToValidate="txtdob" ValidationGroup="check" ErrorMessage="Date format in YYYY-YY"
                        ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{4})[.--]+([0-9]{2})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**Eidt:**

Just change and try it

```
<input id="txtdob" runat="server" type="text" />

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
                ControlToValidate="txtdob" ValidationGroup="check" ErrorMessage="Date format in YYYY-YY"
                ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{4})[./-]+([0-9]{2})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="check" />
        </div>
```

Or  add this line where your code!

```
var m = sAcadYearName.match(^([0-9]{4})[./-]+([0-9]{2})$);
```

It's like validate for :

**2013/14 or 2013-14**

Comment: It's Client side validation ! if you use this code,page  not refreshing. See my Edited Code

Comment: It's okay . Happy Coding !

Answer (score 3):

It depends how complicated you want to go, if you just want to validate numbers it can be as simple as

```
\d\d\d\d-\d\d
```

if you want to be just within 19XX-YY or 20XX-YY then

```
(\b19|\b20)\d\d-\d\d
```

if you need more specific rules (e.g. 1981-99) and you need to write some custom javascripts to perform validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom date validator in jQuery

[**SEE HERE**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage)

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseDate(str) {
  var m = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
  return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2]-1, m[1]) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  It has demos, and a lot of ways to filter form field input.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can go this link here is a good example 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

or you can  check out this link also

[RegEx to match M/YYYY, MM/YYYY , M/YY or MM/YY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944446/regex-to-match-m-yyyy-mm-yyyy-m-yy-or-mm-yy-format)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I have added a regular ecpression validator for my textbox like so.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="txtAcademicYearName_RegularExpressionValidator2"  runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAcademicYearName" ErrorMessage="Enter year in format  YYYY-YY" ValidationExpression="(\b19|\b20)\d\d-\d\d" ForeColor="Red" Display="None"  ValidationGroup="AcademicYear"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```