# How to make custom date validation attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need help to format a date like this in a EditorFor eg. 3/2017 and so on. I try to code but I see something went wrong.

example:

```
public class ValidDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;

        var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
            "MM/yyyy",
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dateTime);

        return isValid;
    }
}

[ValidDate]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Valid Result Examples:

```
1/2017
2/2017
3/2017
4/2017
5/2017
6/2017
7/2017
8/2017
9/2017
10/2017
11/2017
12/2017
```

Comment: Your property is `DateTime` which needs at least values for the day, month and year - none of those values can ever be valid.

Comment: Try using regex as given there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944446/regex-to-match-m-yyyy-mm-yyyy-m-yy-or-mm-yy-format. However, you must declare `Date` property as string to do so, and compare the validation pattern with regex.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked you attribute and found out that  you passed date as M/yyyy format.
That's why you need change attribute as below:

```
public class ValidDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;

        var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
            "M/yyyy",
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dateTime);

        return isValid;
    }
}
```